# Webkit un-invert invert() images?

Tags: css, webkit

I use invert() on some images in my css, it inverts them properly, BUT(here's my problem) when I run invert() on them again to put them back to normal, they are not exactly the same. The brightness or contrast changes and they are a bit washed out. Why is this and what is a way around it? Is there a revert() function of sorts? What exactly is invert() doing to the images?

TIA!

UPDATE; This is the best way to understand the problem(with comments): http://jsbin.com/uzicaz/2/edit

Comment: Can you post a link to an example image?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3qDpx/2/  jsfiddle doesn't seem to run invert() BUT it would be executed twice on the image; which should restore it but rather washes it out

Comment: try running the same code in chrome. see if you get the same result

Comment: I should have mentioned that this problem is affecting all version of Chrome including Chrome 26 which I am currently running... I only care about getting it fixed within the Chrome browser

Comment: To anyone reading this, the webkit-filter:none; below doesn't work for me. For the sake of simplicity, imagine I'm inverting my webpage and want keep the images original. Using the above in this fashion would look like this: html {webkit-filter: invert();} img{webkit-filter: none;} This does not work, the images still get inverted unless I explicitly change it to img{webkit-filter: invert();} Thoughts, ideas, solutions? You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You're applying the same CSS directive using two different selectors.

When you do that, the directive is not applied twice. One of them gets overridden by the other:

[image]

The less significant one is canceled and the more significant one is applied. But the two are identical, so the directive is applied once.

To cancel the first declaration without reapplying it again, set the directive to `none` in the second declaration:

```
img {
  -webkit-filter: invert() brightness(100%) contrast(100%);
}

#photo1 {
  -webkit-filter: none;
}
```

PS The `invert() brightness(100%) contrast(100%)` combination produces a blank-white image for me. If you're tring to make it blank, use `visibility: hidden;` instead.

Comment: Sorry I'm late but this is awesome, I didn't know I could use "none" there instead of "re-inverting". Thanks, I will test it out in the AM and post back here in case anyone else has this same problem.

Comment: So this doesn't work for me? For the sake of simplicity, imagine I'm inverting my webpage and want keep the images original. Using the above in this fashion would look like this: html {webkit-filter: invert();} img{webkit-filter: none;} This does not work, the images still get inverted unless I explicitly change it to img{webkit-filter: invert();} Thoughts, ideas, solutions? You guys are awesome!

Comment: You're applying the initial invert to a parent, not the images. Consider using `html img { -webkit-filter: invert(); }`.

Comment: lolmaus, here's the most eloquent way I can state my problem using your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uzicaz/2/edit

Comment: Okay, my solution is not applicable for your code. Can you please tell me why are you doing that in the first place? That's some quite weird stuff, CSS is not supposed to be used that way.

Comment: lolmaus, I appreciate your help but I also believe that if we used things the way they were intended to be used the internet wouldn't exist... That said, I'm willing to use javascript if I need to BUT I thought there might be an easy css fix or something I overlooked in the webkit spec. Seems like a webkit-filter: restore; would be great here!

Comment: Catalyst, you're right that it's hard to imagine the web with CSS used only the way it's intended to. But this is no excuse to go full retard with inverting and zooming out the `html` element.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think that what you really need is much easier. If all you want is keeping the image as it is, then:

```
img {
  -webkit-filter: invert();
}

#photo1 {
   -webkit-filter: none;
```

}

is your solution. img will be inverted (or whatever you want), but img with id = photo1 will not.
Please notice that it is not that you undo the effect in the element, you are overriding it, so the transform never takes place.